# Turn on and off MacBook Pro Retina connected to a Thunderbolt Display monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt-display

I would like to know if there is a way to turn on and off a Macbook Pro Retina connected to a Thunderbolt Display monitor when it is closed.

Should I open my MacBook Pro Retina each time I need to turn on my computer?

Is the only solution to not turn it off and putting it into sleeping mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can bring up the power menu by pressing Control-Eject. You can also directly sleep (Command-Option-Eject), shut down (Command-Option-Control-Eject), restart (Command-Control-Eject), or turn off the display (Shift-Control-Eject) using the keyboard. You can also press any key to wake a sleeping mac.

There is no known way of turning on recent Macbooks via keyboard except for the power button.

Comment: Where can I find the eject key in my Macbook Pro Retina 15 Early 2013?

Comment: @Alex the internal keyboard has the power key, which works the same. On some versions of osx, external keyboards without a dedicated power or eject key can use f12 instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks @cde - I was looking to turn on my Macbook Pro Retina without opening it, but I see it is impossible.